# Paginação na galeria de fotos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa noite a todos, preciso de ajuda no trecho de código a seguir e uma galeria de fotos e preciso que seja feito a paginação de 9 em 9 fotos já tentei de tudo e não consegui se puderem me ajudar ai

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<?php include("header.php");?>
    <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="overlay-bg">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="menu-container">
                                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                    <div class="dropdown btn btn-danger">
                                        <a href="\index.php" style="color:#ffffff"><b>INÍCIO</b></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="menu-1" class="homepage" style="margin-top:50px;">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 2; $i++) { ?>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                        <div class="overlay">
                                                            <a href="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" data-rel="lightbox">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo$i?>" style="color:red;">Preços</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <img src="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" alt="Image 9">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: veja na resposta o segundo exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função  `glob()` devolve um conjunto de nomes de arquivos ou diretórios correspondentes a um padrão específico. No caso em questão `glob("$pasta{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE)` sendo `$pasta = 'images/gallery/fruteira/';`

O numero de arquivos dentro da pasta `fruteira` é dado por `count($arquivos)`

> Daí por diante fica por conta do conhecimento minimo em PHP para entender a logica do script :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<?php include("header.php");?>
<div class="bg-image">
    <div class="overlay-bg">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="menu-container">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                <div class="dropdown btn btn-danger">
                                    <a href="\index.php" style="color:#ffffff"><b>INÍCIO</b></a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="menu-1" class="homepage" style="margin-top:50px;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <?php 

                                        $pasta = 'images/gallery/fruteira/';
                                        $arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);

                                        $maisPaginas=count($arquivos)-$fim;

                                        if ($_GET["pag"]==""){
                                            $inicio=1;
                                            $fim=9;
                                        }else{
                                            $fim=$_GET["pag"]*9;
                                            $inicio=($fim-9)+1;
                                        }

                                        if($fim>=count($arquivos)){
                                            $fim=count($arquivos);
                                        }

                                        for ($i=$inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++) { 
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                    <div class="overlay">
                                                        <a href="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" data-rel="lightbox">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo$i?>" style="color:red;">Preços</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <img src="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" alt="Image <?php echo$i; ?>" title="Image <?php echo$i; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    if (($_GET["pag"]=="")&&(count($arquivos)>$fim)){
                                        echo " <a href=\"?pag=2\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>proxima</b></a> ";
                                    }


                                    if (($_GET["pag"]>1)&&(count($arquivos)>=$fim)){
                                        echo " <a href=\"?pag=".($_GET["pag"]-1)."\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>anterior</b></a>";
                                    }


                                    if (($_GET["pag"]!="")&&(count($arquivos)>$fim)){
                                        echo " <a href=\"?pag=".($_GET["pag"]+1)."\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>proxima</b></a>";
                                    }

                                    ?>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Para fazer de acordo com o comentário do autor** `[Primeira][1][2][3][ultima]`

**CSS:**

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0000ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.negrito {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.corrente {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML + PHP**

```
 <div class="bg-image">
    <div class="overlay-bg">
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="menu-container">
                            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                <div class="dropdown btn btn-danger">
                                    <a href="\index.php" style="color:#ffffff"><b>INÍCIO</b></a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="menu-1" class="homepage" style="margin-top:50px;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <?php 

                                        $pasta = 'images/gallery/fruteira/';
                                        $arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);

                                        $quantArquivos = count($arquivos);

                                        $maisPaginas=$quantArquivos-$fim;

                                        if ($_GET["pag"]==""){
                                            $inicio=1;
                                            $fim=9;
                                        }else{
                                            $fim=$_GET["pag"]*9;
                                            $inicio=($fim-9)+1;
                                        }

                                        if($fim>=$quantArquivos){
                                            $fim=$quantArquivos;
                                        }

                                        for ($i=$inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++) { 
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                    <div class="overlay">
                                                        <a href="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.png" data-rel="lightbox">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-expand">Imagem<?php echo$i; ?></i>
                                                        </a><br>
                                                        <!--comentado para não poluir a apresentação do exemplo de paginação
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo$i?>" style="color:red;">Preços</button>
                                                        -->
                                                    </div>
                                                    <img src="images/gallery/fruteira/<?php echo$i; ?>.png" alt="Image <?php echo$i; ?>" title="Image <?php echo$i; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                                                            <?php

                                    if (($_GET["pag"]==1)||($_GET["pag"]=="")){
                                            echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[Primeira]</span> ";
                                    }else{
                                            echo " <a href=\"?pag=1\">[Primeira]</a> ";
                                    }

                                    for ($k=1; $k <=  ceil(($quantArquivos/9)); $k++) { 

                                        if ($_GET["pag"]==$k){
                                            echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[".$k."]</span>";
                                        }else{
                                            if (($_GET["pag"]=="")&&($k==1)){
                                                echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[1]</span>";
                                            }else{
                                                echo " <a href=\"?pag=".$k."\">[".$k."]</a> ";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if ($_GET["pag"]==ceil(($quantArquivos/9))){
                                            echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[Ultima]</span> ";
                                    }else{
                                            echo " <a href=\"?pag=".ceil(($quantArquivos/9))."\" style=\"color:#0000ff\">[Ultima]</a>";
                                    }

                                    ?>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionando 1000%

Comment: muito obg mesmo ajudou de mais

Comment: pronto amigo! é que sou novo aqui, kkkk me desculpe.

Comment: teria como colocar tipo um botão: [Primeira] [1][2][3][ultima] nesse codigo tentei eu mesmo fazer isso mas nao deu mt certo não

Comment: @TulioVieira veja na resposta o segundo exemplo

Comment: deu certo nao vou criar um post com o codigo e imagens como ficou

Comment: pucliquei la em baixo um post da uma olhada

Comment: pode deixar encontrei a soluçao variavel errada no lugar de$quantArquivos é $maisPaginas

Answer (score 1):

quando aperto a primeira funciona na boa mas a ultima nao funciona nem os numeros.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="pt-br">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="pt-br">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="pt-br"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br">
<!--<![endif]-->

<body>
<?php include("header.php");?>
    <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="overlay-bg">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Begin Content -->
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="menu-container">
                                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                    <div class="dropdown btn btn-danger">
                                        <a href="\index.php" style="color:#ffffff"><b>INÍCIO</b></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="menu-1" class="homepage" style="margin-top:50px;">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <?php $pasta = 'images/gallery/roupeiro/';
                                                $arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);

                                                $maisPaginas=count($arquivos)-$fim;

                                                if ($_GET["pag"]==""){
                                                    $inicio=1;
                                                    $fim=9;
                                                }else{
                                                    $fim=$_GET["pag"]*9;
                                                    $inicio=($fim-9)+1;
                                                }

                                                if($fim>=count($arquivos)){
                                                    $fim=count($arquivos);
                                                }

                                                for ($i=$inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++) { 
                                             ?>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                        <div class="overlay">
                                                            <a href="images/gallery/roupeiro/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" data-rel="lightbox">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo$i?>" style="color:red;">Preços</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <img src="images/gallery/roupeiro/<?php echo$i; ?>.jpg" alt="Image 9">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php

                                    if (($_GET["pag"]==1)||($_GET["pag"]=="")){
                                            echo " <a class='dropdown btn btn-danger' href=\"?pag=1\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>Primeira</b></a> ";
                                    }else{
                                            echo " <a class='dropdown btn btn-danger' href=\"?pag=1\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>Primeira</b></a> ";
                                    }

                                    for ($k=1; $k <=  ceil(($quantArquivos/9)); $k++) { 

                                        if ($_GET["pag"]==$k){
                                            echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[".$k."]</span>";
                                        }else{
                                            if (($_GET["pag"]=="")&&($k==1)){
                                                echo " <span class=\"corrente\">[1]</span>";
                                            }else{
                                                echo " <a href=\"?pag=".$k."\">[".$k."]</a> ";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if ($_GET["pag"]==ceil(($quantArquivos/9))){
                                            echo " <a class='dropdown btn btn-danger' href=\"?pag=".ceil(($quantArquivos/9))."\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>Ultima</b></a>";
                                    }else{
                                            echo " <a class='dropdown btn btn-danger' href=\"?pag=".ceil(($quantArquivos/9))."\" style=\"color:#0000ff\"><b>Ultima</b></a>";
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A mudança na declaração do laço for impede o reconhecimento da paginação (pois o for será executado sempre 20 vezes, e não dividindo em partes de 9)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo olha aqui

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu entendi mas o erro que estava dando era variavel errada $quantArquivos <  a correta era $maisPaginas já resolvi mt obg pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Criei um pequeno controle para a paginação em PHP (opcionalmente pode ser feito em javascript). Basicamente é utilizada uma variavel offset que deve ser passada pela url, e essa variavel irá determinar qual imagem deve ser impressa. Adicionamento criei um array para armazenar parte da url das imagens (para facilitar a paginação), pequenas alterações no laço for e foram adicionados dois links um para proximo e outro para anterior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<?php //include("header.php");?>
    <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="overlay-bg">
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="menu-container">
                                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                    <div class="dropdown btn btn-danger">
                                        <a href="\index.php" style="color:#ffffff"><b>INÍCIO</b></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="menu-1" class="homepage" style="margin-top:50px;">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            <?php 
                        $offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 1;
                        $imagens = ['images/gallery/fruteira/', 'images/gallery/tipo1/', 'images/gallery/tipo2/'
                        , 'images/gallery/tipo3/', 'images/gallery/tipo4/', 'images/gallery/tipo5/', 
                        'images/gallery/tipo6/', 'images/gallery/tipo7/', 'images/gallery/tipo8/',
                        'images/gallery/tipo9/', 'images/gallery/tipo10/', 'images/gallery/tipo11/', 
                        'images/gallery/tipo12/', 'images/gallery/tipo13/', 'images/gallery/tipo14/',
                        'images/gallery/tipo15/', 'images/gallery/tipo16/', 'images/gallery/tipo17/',
                        'images/gallery/tipo17/'];

                        for ($i=$offset; $i < ($offset + 9) && $i <= count($imagens); $i++) { ?>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                    <div class="portfolio-item">
                                                        <div class="overlay">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo $imagens[$i - 1] . $i; ?>.jpg" data-rel="lightbox">
                                                                <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong<?php echo$i?>" style="color:red;">Preços</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo $imagens[$i - 1] . $i; ?>.jpg" alt="Imagem: <?php echo $imagens[$i - 1] . $i; ?>.jpg">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                    <?php 
                        $anterior_offset = ($offset - 9) < 1 ? 1 : ($offset - 9);
                        $proximo_offset = ($offset + 9) > count($imagens) ? $offset : ($offset + 9);                    
                    ?>
                    <a href="?offset=<?php echo $anterior_offset ?>">Anterior</a>
                    <a href="?offset=<?php echo $proximo_offset ?>">Próximo</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php //include("footer.php"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui está um recorte do que eu consigui obter (sem estilização):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vou testar aqui e te falo mas como ficaria em JS? acho que seria mais pratico não?

Comment: tentei aqui mas nao deu certo não

Comment: vou comentar abaixo para vc ver o codigo